# Windbg shows info dialog that it cannot open MFC source file from devdiv.visualstudio.com

Tags: git, visual-studio, debugging, visual-c++, windbg

Windbg 10.0.20348.1 shows this info dialog with below message when single stepping through MFC code:

The file 'https://devdiv.visualstudio.com/DevDiv/_apis/git/repositories/msvc/items?path=src/vctools/VC7libs/Ship/ATLMFC/Src/MFC/wincore.cpp&versionDescriptor[versionOptions]=0&versionDescriptor[versionType]=2&versionDescriptor[version]=0a7a0c7ef973187f59b10575b76ab07d8e7b3bbe&resolveLfs=true&$format=octetStream&api-version=5.0&download=false' cannot be opened

Screenshot :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1165676/windbg-shows-info-dialog-that-it-cannot-open-mfc-c

Im seeing this since a few months and looks like windbg is trying to load MFC source files from MS git repos. Has it worked for anyone ? Has MFC source loaded directly from MS git repo?

Answer (score 0):

The link you see points to the `devdiv`subdomain. DevDiv is short for Developer Division, the Microsoft development department. While you can try to sign in under that URL with a Microsoft account, you will probably not be granted access.

Download [Search Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/downloads/) and search for the file `wincore.cpp` on your hard disk. If you installed Visual Studio with MFC sources, you should find it somewhere, likely in a `mfc/src` folder.

You should then be able to use [`.srcpath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-srcpath---lsrcpath--set-source-path-) to point WinDbg to those files.

Other than that, there's rarely a need for stepping through Microsoft code, except if you want to prove that there's a bug. It might be easier to write a MRE to reprodice the bug and file an issue at Microsoft instead.